# Session management with xdmp:http functions in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

Is there native support or a utility library for session management with `xdmp:http` functions in MarkLogic? Something similar to Python `requests` Session object or Node `request` cookie jar?

Python request session: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects
Node request cookie jar: https://github.com/request/request#requestjar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`xdmp:set-session-field()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-session-field) and [`xdmp:get-session-field-names()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-session-field) to achieve the same

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help!